# JB Exclusion Script Using DE Attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I am trying to use the below exclusion script in JB to exclude anyone with a matching UID value to the entry DE (which is a different DE than the one referenced in the script).

```
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Welcome Email Test", "uid", AttributeValue("uid"))) > 0)
```

Welcome Email Test contains these value:
Email Address: lily.***@gmail.com
uid: 1234

Sending DE (which is the target DE to a test form used as an entry source):
Email Address: lydia.ferguson@***.com
uid: 1234

(hiding email addresses, as they are live inboxes)

The email addresses are different, per my client's use case, but the UID's should match, therefore excluding the matched one from the send. The UID is not the primary key or subscriberkey.

I have tested this in Content Builder, and it works as expected. But not in Journey Builder.